# Css - Create header gradient and pattern

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is there any way to made the same style like in the image with CSS?

[image: Image pattern]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5 allows us to draw multiple background images on any element. We can use CSS3's [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) and [`repeating-linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) functions to create 2 background images and draw them on the respective element.

Following code will create the background you need:

```
#header {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
                                                        rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 15px,
                                                        transparent 15px,
                                                        transparent 25px),
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, brown, red);
}
```

> **Note:** Order of images in `background-image` property is important. Swapping
>   them won't create the effect you need.

**Output Image:**

[image: Header with background]

**Working Demo:**

```css
#header {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15), rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 15px, transparent 15px, transparent 25px), linear-gradient(to bottom, brown, red);
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"></header>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, this is so much more simplistic then the above answer from aashi, and you actually explain your answer. Good Job!

Comment: yes this is perfect, I really appreciate your help, indeed this is the answer

Comment: one question please if I set the height to 45px is not look so good, can you try please?

Comment: @Robert You can change the color stops and adjust as per your needs. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vne1sc8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below CSS

```
 <div class="meter red">
      <span style="width: 25%"></span>
    </div>

.meter { 
    height: 20px;  /* Can be anything */
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.meter > span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
  );
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red > span {
  background-color: #f0a3a3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
}

.meter > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
    transparent 25%, 
    transparent 50%, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
    transparent 75%, 
    transparent
  );
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  animation: move 2s linear infinite;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```